# is it possible to run drupal 6 on mysql 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, drupal-6

Currently my website is running on MySQL version 5.2 with drupal 6 and now i want to upgrade both apache server and MYSQL database.

New Apache server Version =  2.2.3
MySql Version = 5.6

will my site works on MySQL 5.6

Comment: Why not ask/look on the Drupal web site

Answer (score 5):

Normally you will not have any problem but it depends on the modules that you have installed. Because MySQL 5.6 has a lot of new reserved words it is possible that a module will fail.

The best way to test it, is to create a backup of your site and create a local version in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. Drupal requirements:

**Web server**

- Apache, Nginx, or Microsoft IIS

**Database server**

- Drupal 5: MySQL 3.23.17 or higher
- Drupal 6: MySQL 4.1 or higher, PostgreSQL 7.1,
- Drupal 7: MySQL 5.0.15 or higher with PDO, PostgreSQL 8.3 or higher
  with PDO, SQLite 3.3.7 or higher
- Note: Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle are supported by an additional
  module

**PHP**

- Drupal 5: PHP 4.4.0 - 5.2.x (5.2 recommended, 5.3 not supported)
- Drupal 6: PHP 4.4.0 or higher (5.2 recommended)
- Drupal 7: PHP 5.2.5 or higher (5.3 recommended)
- Drupal 8: PHP 5.5.9  (was raised  - see https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/php#8)